# how to enforce checkout for only one file and not the whole library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, library, check-out

I have a document library in SharePoint 2010, and I would like to enforce checkout for only one of the files and not the whole library. Is that possible?

Comment: I have a reverse issue. I'd like all documents to be check out while editing, but seems like when I checked in multiple documents to the library, it automatically enforces check out on only one document and I am not able to set it for all the other documents even though the check out requirement is marked as Required 'Yes' in library versioning section. The other files do have data validation and conditional formatting, do you think that is why it is overriding the Check out condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Enforcing check out before a file can be edited is a setting that can only be applied at the library level, not for a single document. The same goes for versioning. It's all or nothing.

Comment: Thank you teylyn for your reply. I know that checkout is a list-based feature, this is why I was looking for a not-out-of-box workaround.